# Javascript/Jquery Get part of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Is it possible to get the first number of strings like these?

```
loadTabContent('90', this, 'tabTabel', null);
loadTabContent('101', this, 'tabTabel', null);
```

In the case of the first, i want a variable to return '90', in case of the last, I want it to return '101'. How do I do this? The length of the number is variable, but always starts at the same place.

Comment: Doesn't really look like strings? Anyway, `str.match(/\d+/)` should get the first number!

Comment: I see my strings aren't correct indeed. Do you know if I have an onclick attribute, like `onclick="loadTabContent('90', this, 'tabTabel', null);"`, if I can put the `loadTabContent('90', this, 'tabTabel', null);` in a string? I tried `var tabString = $("#" + tabID).attr("onclick");`, but javascript puts everything in the string, and not only the string value of the onclick attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var re = /'\d+(.*?)'/;
 var sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
 var results = [];
 var i = 0;
 for (var matches = re.exec(sourcestring); matches != null; matches = re.exec(sourcestring)) {
 results[i] = matches;
 for (var j=0; j<matches.length; j++) {
  alert("results["+i+"]["+j+"] = " + results[i][j]);
  }
 i++;
}
```

```
$matches Array:
  (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => '90'
        [1] => '101'
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
    )

 )
```